# useEffect vs useEffect0 in ReasonML

Tags: use-effect, reason, reason-react

I am trying understand what the difference is between:

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    let timerId = Js.Global.setInterval(() => tick(), 1000);
    Some(() => Js.Global.clearInterval(timerId));
  });
 React.useEffect0(() => {
    let timerId = Js.Global.setInterval(() => tick(), 1000);
    Some(() => Js.Global.clearInterval(timerId));
  });
```

They both have the same type signature and both compile but the `useEffect0` does nothing:

```
// useEffect0 : unit => option(unit => unit) => unit
// useEffect : unit => option(unit => unit) => unit
```

To use the example at https://reasonml.github.io/reason-react/blog/2019/04/10/react-hooks, it uses `useEffect` but if you change so that it uses `useState` instead of `useReducer` you have to change `useEffect` to `useEffect0`

Original version using [`useEffect0`](https://nit.sketch.sh/?code=FDC2HsBMFcBsFMAEBhc0B2AXeAnRBeRAb2EwE8AHJAQwGNMBLcdA4RRAH0QBUHaBrANwhyVRAGdM1bAWJtEtNFgBciBlgA0wAL7DgAbQACOeHUwA6RaArN4WALrAEmRKGr8khABQBKAgD45dmdEL0lpeA1ESAZxCmlaAAs-QgAlU3pzaHF4dJhaXC95djCpbCizJnQU-2L2CQB3Bkwk0MrmPxJ6+q5eAQDiRQxMVXDsSyUXAGpEAEZtOvZtLW6iIZVEAAYF9h89dnSzLJyAUQAzM-h6Ta9fAa76kMZQXABJSFkAKXFzAHFYcAAI2osHMOUwrywuAAbiDbjVorF4i1El4+vwfFFZpscXs6gBlcAveEDb5-AHA0G0BDUHCQ7A4WGwLzPN6QHw+eTaPHseQAHhi0P8REO4mYh0ykhw6gA5qVpegZQB9cBnJXqTClCITYYc7R8gD0gv8wl0Oj0EswABEAPIAWXS5hM6EguG44BOCBeWAA6s1Eu8vHzUMNcIgDf4ogAiHDgcCYKN7IA):

```
type action =
  | Tick;

type state = {
  count: int,
};

[@react.component]
let make = () => {
  let (state, dispatch) = React.useReducer(
    (state, action) =>
      switch (action) {
      | Tick => {count: state.count + 1}
      },
    {count: 0}
  );

  React.useEffect0(() => {
    let timerId = Js.Global.setInterval(() => dispatch(Tick), 1000);
    Some(() => Js.Global.clearInterval(timerId))
  });

  <div>{ReasonReact.string(string_of_int(state.count))}</div>;
};
```

After removing `useReducer` and using [`useEffect`](https://nit.sketch.sh/?code=FDC2HsBMFcBsFMAEBhc0B2AXeAnRBeRAbxGEwE8AHJAZ0wENsDjhFEBjNLALkQEssAGmABfANykA2gAEc8eu0wA6TqErh08LAF1gCTIlD0A1kkIAKAJQEAfC32JzdRvEGJIfGpUbsAFtcIAJXlFJWgaeABlBmxzK3wbVjZiTgxMXgAGESTLCQdMPnZjAni7Dy8fX3MAfQSiVJ5EZ2wVLgMAakQARhFcpOCFZXD4AFEAMzH4RTiAuxJkxHy+UFwASUhmACkaJQBxWHAAI3pYJQjMVaxcADcTmdtEAqKrNy6M976FyPAV+4TEbZ7A7HU7sBD0HCXbA4W6wcwFFaQyCWSxJXoSNhJAA8HmuNiIAxoGgGoToOAEAHMnJhyegKdVwGNqgJMNSXK00iiRFiAPS4mwScQgIXAEmYAAiAHkALLBJRydCQXAAFXAIwQKywAHU+JhfOtzFjUGlcIgeTY3AAiHDgcCYS25IA):

```
[@react.component]
let make = () => {
let (state, dispatch) = React.useState(()=>
    {count: 0}
  );
let tick =()=> dispatch(_=>{count: state.count + 1});
  React.useEffect(() => {
    let timerId = Js.Global.setInterval(() => tick(), 1000);
    Some(() => Js.Global.clearInterval(timerId))
  });

  <div>{ReasonReact.string(string_of_int(state.count))}</div>;
};
```

So why does the call change when using the different structure?

Any links or explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`React.useEffect(f)` in Reason compiles to `React.useEffect(f)` in JavaScript. `React.useEffect0(f)` in Reason compiles to `React.useEffect(f, [])` in JavaScript.

The difference is that second `[]` argument that's inserted in the JavaScript. By default, `useEffect` in JavaScript fires with *every* render. By adding the empty array in the second argument, we're telling React to only fire it once, when the component first renders.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. So the first example `useEffect0` fires once and does what ever is in `useReducer` once, here `Tick`. In the `hook` example, `useEffect` fires the `tick()` once because of the added empty array. Does that make sense?

Comment: see also [reason.chat](https://reasonml.chat/t/useeffect-vs-useeffect0/2287/2) answer.